# Capistrano asking me for password, but I can't enter it

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

I am using Capistrano to deploy my code. 
After the deploy, I have to restart the apache. I am doing it with this code:

```
role :app, %w{deployer@ip}
server '91.185.209.70', user: 'deployer', roles: %w{app}, password: "password"
set :ssh_options, {
    forward_agent: false,
    auth_methods: %w(password),
    password: 'password',
    user: 'deployer',
}
 namespace :deploy do
   desc 'Restart application'
   task :restart do
     on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
       execute "sudo service apache2 restart"
     end
   end
 end
```

But I keep geeting this and **I cant** enter the password at the bottom - keyboard disabled:

[image: problem with password]

Also, why is the restart taks not called automatically after the deploy? I have to call it manually.

Comment: Why do you want to restart apache? Restart your rack ruby server instead(unicorn/passenger/thin or whatever you possibly use)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and after searching for a while I stumbled upon this gem:

https://github.com/kentaroi/sshkit-sudo

It's very simple!

Add to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sshkit'
```

Bundle:

```
$ bundle
```

Require in `Capfile`:

```
require 'sshkit/sudo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Password authentication can be done via ask in your deploy environment file (e.g.: config/environments/production.rb)

```
# Capistrano > 3.2.0 supports echo: false
ask(:password, nil, echo: false)

server '91.185.209.70',
       user: 'deployer',
       roles: %w{app},
       password: fetch(:password)
```

http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/how-can-i-get-capistrano-to-prompt-for-a-password/